# WebStorm indentation (autoformat)

Tags: javascript, d3.js, webstorm

### TL;DR

is there a way to make more fine-grained rules about autoformatting in WebStorm?

### The long story

I'm writing JavaScript code in JetBrains' WebStorm. I love the IDE, but there's one thing I cannot figure out, and it's got to do with how the autoformatting feature formats mike bostock's D3 library.

A convention when writing code using D3 is that methods are chained, with the indentation used as a visual clue for the selection that is returned: a method returning the same selection is indented normally at 4 spaces; one returning a new selection is indented with 2 spaces. E.g.:

```
d3.select('svg#chart')
    .attr('height', 600)
    .attr('width', 800)
    .attr('class', 'myChart')
  .append('g')
    .attr('class', 'bigGroup')
    .style(...)
    .data(myData)
  .enter().append('rect')
    .attr('height', 30)
```

Now, this indentation is destroyed, with all indentation reset to 4 spaces, when running `Code | Reformat Code`.

The rules that are followed are found under `Settings | Editor | Code Style | JavaScript`. They are not detailed enough to accommodate this use case, and so I was wondering if I'm missing something here or if I should just live with not using autoformatting.

### Edit

By using formatting markers like this:

```
d3.select('svg#chart')
    .attr('height', 600)
    .attr('width', 800)
    .attr('class', 'myChart')//@formatting:off
  .append('g')//@formatting:on
    .attr('class', 'bigGroup')
    .style(...)
    .data(myData)//@formatting:off
  .enter().append('rect')//@formatting:on
    .attr('height', 30)
```

the formatting stays intact. As pointed out by @LazyOne, only comments are scanned for formatting markers. The user can specify which markers are used - so that instead of `//@formatting:off` and `//@formatting:on`, others are recognised by the IDE. I was hoping for a solution that doesn't rely on markers at all, and do something like pattern matching on the source code itself.

But I guess this is what I'll have to use for now. It's not that it doesn't work. It's just that it's hard to maintain, and fugly. Needing a comment *only* after the offending line would already be a big improvement. If anyone is aware of other JavaScript formatting tools out there that do accommodate my use case, I'd love to hear

Comment: I was thinking it might be possible to use regexps in the formatting on/off fields (https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/help/code-style.html#formatter_options) to filter out the lines with the offending methods. But it's not working, or I'm doing it wrong

Comment: *"But it's not working, or I'm doing it wrong"* 1) What pattern(s) exactly have you tried? 2) Does non-regex option works?

Comment: 1) In order to get the above case working, I tried stuff like starting: 'append' and ending: 'ppend\(', and variants on that. 2) yes

Comment: You wanted it to be triggered on actual code (e.g. `.append('g')` line from your code sample)? AFAIK it does not work like that -- it only works on comments -- so that you can use it instead of default `@formatter:off` (e.g. list more than one trigger)